# Inject a dependency into a angular factory and access the dependency

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

I have added with bower the angular-moment library.

I followed the how-to of the angular-moment author and added also both scripts to my index.html file and to the karma.conf.js file with the files option including certain files.

How can I access in my app/dateFactory the angular-moment object to do time stuff?

**app/dateFactory**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('clientApp', ['angularMoment']).factory('dateFactory', function () {


    function dateRange(startDate, endDate) {


    }

    // Public API here
    return {
        dateRange: dateRange
    }
});
```

UPDATE => running this code the factory instance is defined!

```
angular.module('clientApp').factory('dateFactory', function() {
    function dateRange(startDate, endDate) {
       var bla = moment.format()

        return [];
        //return Enumerable.range(0, endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days + 1).Select(offset => startDate.AddDays(offset)).toArray();
    }

    // Public API here
    return {
        dateRange: dateRange
    }
});
```

UPDATE => running this code the factory instance is undefined!

```
angular.module('clientApp', ['angularMoment']).factory('dateFactory', ['moment', function(moment) {
    function dateRange(startDate, endDate) {


        moment.format() //for example

        return [];
        //return Enumerable.range(0, endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days + 1).Select(offset => startDate.AddDays(offset)).toArray();
    }

    // Public API here
    return {
        dateRange: dateRange
    }
}]);
```

Thats the way the factory is created:

```
describe('Service: dateFactory', function () {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(module('clientApp'));

  // instantiate service
  var dateFactory;
  beforeEach(inject(function (_dateFactory_) {
    dateFactory = _dateFactory_;
  }));

  it('should do something', function () {

      var data = dateFactory.dateRange(new Date(2014,1,1), new Date(2014,1,15));

    expect(!!dateFactory).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can inject the 'moment' global into your factory.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('clientApp', ['angularMoment']).factory('dateFactory', ['moment', function(moment) {
    function dateRange(startDate, endDate) {
        moment.format() //for example

    }

    // Public API here
    return {
        dateRange: dateRange
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Amir when I use your code then my factory "dateFactory" instance is not created anymore its always undefined. You know why? Please see my updated code above.

Comment: I also get this error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: momentProvider <- moment <- dateFactory

Comment: I got it working now without your code... moment.format() is undefined... and second you can not inject 3rd party scripts that way only with requireJS I found out.